# Could not connext to Proxy in Android

Tags: java, android, proxy

I'm programming an application with internet uses. The Problem is, that i've a proxy problem. I've already read some articles in the net but nothing helps. When i start the avd from command-line with 
`emulator -avd <avd-Name> -http-proxy http:<proxyname>:<proxyip> -debug-proxy`

I had the error Message:
`Could not connect to proxy at http:0: Unkown socket error (Winsock=0xffffffff) errno=2: No such file or directory`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the correct syntax?

It's supposed to be one of the following:

```
http://<server>:<port>
http://<username>:<password>@<server>:<port>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

If it doesn't work that way, maybe try a(nother) public proxy

Comment: I'm sure I try the right Syntax... 
But my mistake was that I don't have to write the word `proxy` before the proxyname. But my problem now is, that the emulator recognise the proxy but can't connect to the internet. The command-error is always :
`tcp:(null)(1516): header sent, receiving first answer line
tcp:(null)(1516): received 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'
tcp:(null)(1516): connection refused, error=400
http_service_connect: trying to connect to (null)
http_service_connect: using HTTP rewriter
tcp:(null)(1500): connecting
http_service_free`

Comment: I solved the problem to connect from the emulator to the Internet through the proxy :) :)
there is a problem with the api Version 2.1 and 2.2. I had only to create a new emulator with version 2.3.3 and its gone :)
In the eclipse i didn't some settings only in the emulator networksettings.
But my application still has no internet connection..
any Help?

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission to your Manifest file?      

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  

If you did, make sure your emulator has Internet, by using it's browser.

Comment: Yes i add the internet permission in the manifest file. But should i add it into the application part? or not?
My emulator has internet because i came into the internet with the browser

Comment: Yeah I solved the problem. The problem wasn't mine. It was the API version 7. I changed the API version to 8 and the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

When emulator -debug-proxy says:
`tcp:(null)(29): received 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'

tcp:(null)(29): connection refused, error=400

http_service_connect: trying to connect to (null)

http_service_connect: using HTTP rewriter

tcp:(null)(30): connecting

tcp:(null)(30): connected to http proxy, sending header

tcp:(null)(30): sending 27 bytes:

43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 20 28 6e 75 6c 6c 29 20 48    CONNECT (null) H

54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 0d 0a                   TTP/1.1....`



In Linux you can try to unset "http_proxy" environment variable:
`$ unset http_proxy`
and then run the emulator again